# Как и какую библиотеку Jquery подключить к сайту на Denwer локальном сервере чтобы работал JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, denwer

Пытаюсь написать сайт при помощи локального сервера денвер необходимо использование JS и подключение Jquery, у меня следующий код
ее подключения<script type "text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

Также посоветовали сделать, вот так

*<script type "text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous">*

но всё равно не работает

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: $(document).ready (function () {
 $("#done").click (function () {
 $('#messageShow').hide ();
 var name = $("#name").val ();
 var email = $("#email").val ();
 var message = $("#message").val ();
 var fail = "";

Comment: if (name.length < 3) fail = "Имя меньше 3-х символов";
 else if (email.split ('@').length - 1 == 0 || email.split ('.').length - 1 == 0)
 fail = "Вы ввели некорректный email";
  else if (message.length < 20)
 fail = "Сообщение менее 20-ти символов";
 if (fail != "") {

Comment: $('#messageShow').html (fail + "<div class ='clear'><br></div>");
 $('#messageShow').show ();
 return false; }
 $.ajax ({
 url: '/ajax/feedback.php',
 type: 'POST',
 cache: false,
 data: {'name': name, 'email': email,  'message': message},
 dataType: 'html',
 succsess: function (data) {
 $('#messageShow').html (data + "<div class = 'clear'><br></div>");
 $('#messageShow').show (); } }); }) });

Comment: короче такой вот код...(

Comment: Не удержусь: Денвер мягко говоря сильно устарел =)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan знаю( Препод в вузе требует именно его к сожалению

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов Не работает джава скрипт, я создала отдельный файл написала там <nosctipt>jahdgajgj</noscript>, он эти буквы не вывел следовательно джава скрипт должен работать. У меня там такой код который должен показывать ошибки в форме регистрации мол неправильный email слишком короткое имя и так далее

Comment: https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/OJXbYYw?editors=1111    списывай

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов Спасибо большое, уточнить хочу  вот это получается перед <script> писать не надо:<script type "text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">, и в чем может быть проблема если кнопка не работает?

Comment: <script type "text/javascript" src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> это надо добавить в html и также подключить свой скрипт строкой ниже